# Split string on non-alphanumerics in PHP? Is it possible with php's native function?

Tags: php, regex, split, native, pcre

I was trying to split a string on non-alphanumeric characters or simple put I want to split words. The approach that immediately came to my mind is to use regular expressions.

**Example:**
`$string = 'php_php-php php';

$splitArr = preg_split('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $string);`

But there are two problems that I see with this approach.

1. It is not a native php function, and is totally dependent on the PCRE Library running on server.
2. An equally important problem is that what if I have punctuation in a word
   **Example:**
   `$string = 'U.S.A-men's-vote';

   $splitArr = preg_split('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $string);`
   Now this will spilt the string as `[{U}{S}{A}{men}{s}{vote}]`
   But I want it as `[{U.S.A}{men's}{vote}]`

So my question is that:

- How can we split them according to words?
- Is there a possibility to do it with php native function or in some other way where we are not dependent?

Regards

Comment: What is your definition of a word? It is allowed periods? What about something like `this sentence.and this one too.`? And what about `I am sure this regex is a no-go but I'll use it anyway.`

Comment: It depends on what you define as "word". For `U.S.A` to be a word, you'd need a non-space-padded stop mark to not be a word separator. So you could split on whitespaces, question marks, commas, colons, and so on, OR spaced stop marks.

Comment: It is possible. Iterate over the string (char by char) and apply your own rules whether the char belongs to a word or not.

Comment: `preg_split` is not native? Please show me a PHP installation since the late 1920s that does not support `preg_split`

Comment: So you're also not using `mysql`/`mysqli`/`PDO`, because these are *extensions*? What about `mb_*`? You just have to be realistic at some point...

Comment: @LeonardChallis That is the real issue. Actually I am making a search using google and bing api. The api sometimes return URLs that we don't need. Like it will send me a link that has the word I searched for on the page but not in its url. Now I only want to get urls that has the word I searched for in the URL. The problem is that if a user searched for USA and the url contains U.S.A or vice-versa, we have a problem. I thought that there might be a solution where a word is pre-defined in php or some other library. I guess that it is not.

Comment: "word" is a predefined concept in PHP and other regex libraries: any collection of alphanumeric characters and underscores.  In your case you have a non-standard definition that fits your particular problem, which is why there is nothing pre-made that does it.

Comment: @dan1111 Yes I agree with you. But try explaining that to a non-technical client.

Comment: There are too many fringe cases to consider and not enough of a [mcve] to confidently post an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a case for [str_word_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) using the oft forgotten 1 or 2 value for the second argument, and with a 3rd argument to include hyphens, full stops and apostrophes (or whatever other characters you wish to treat as word-parts) as part of a word; followed by an [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to [trim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) those characters from the beginning or end of the resultant array values, so you only include them when they're actually embedded in the "word"

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think considering my situation this will give me the closest to best results. Not 100% accurate but almost there.

Answer (score 3):

Either you have PHP installed (then you also have PCRE), or you don't. So your first point is a non-issue.

Then, if you want to exclude punctuation from your splitting delimiters, you need to add them to your character class:

```
preg_split('/[^a-z0-9.\']+/i', $string);
```

If you want to treat punctuation characters differently depending on context (say, make a dot only be a delimiter if followed by whitespace), you can do that, too:

```
preg_split('/\.\s+|[^a-z0-9.\']+/i', $string);
```

Comment: Well, it *is* possible to have a PHP installation without `preg_*` functions enabled. In practice it just doesn't really happen.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, you might want to try (add as many separators as needed)

```
$splitArr = preg_split('/[\s,!?;:-]+|[.]\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

You'd then have to handle the case of a "quoted" word (it's not so easy to do in a regular expression, because 'is" "this' quoted? And how?).

So I think it's best to keep ' and " within words (so that "it's" is a single word, and "they 'll" is two words) and then deal with those cases separately. For example a regexp would have some trouble in correctly handling

```
they 're 'just friends'. Or that's what they say.
```

while having "'re" and a sequence of words of which the first is left-quoted and the last is right-quoted, the first not being a known sequence ('s, 're, 'll, 'd ...) may be handled at application level.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a php-problem, but a logical one.

Words could be concatenated by a -. Abbrevations could look like short sentences.

You can match your example directly by creating a solution that fits only on this particular phrase. But you cant get a solution for all possible phrases. That would require a neuronal-computing based content-recognition.